# Unbalanced parenthesis using __attribute__ in g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors

Today I tried clang on a project I have developed some time ago. I was suprised when it encountered a compilation error, since I had compiled my project successfully using g++.

This short snippet reproduces the line where the error was encountered:

```
int main() {
    __attribute__((aligned(16)) char arr[5];
}
```

Which produces this error:

```
test.cpp:2:32: error: expected ')'
    __attribute__((aligned(16)) char arr[5];
                               ^
                               )
```

As you can see, there is an umbalanced parenthesis. There are three '(', and two ')'. This clearly looks like it should actually produce a compilation error.

Is this a valid usage of this keyword? I can't seem to find anything on [the documentation](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) that indicates it is.

I'm using g++ 4.5.2 and clang 2.8.

Note that this error is detected when using gcc instead of g++.

Comment: The [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) states *"The keyword `__attribute__` allows you to specify special attributes of variables or structure fields. **This keyword is followed by an attribute specification inside double parentheses"***.So it doesn't say it in precise explicit words about closing with same number of parenthesis but all gcc examples show matching parenthesis so looks like a bug.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it actually is a bug. I can't find anything that could indicate the opposite.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas clang supports it. I mean, it really looks like g++ is not parsing that expresion correctly. clang is doing the right thing(at least I suspect so... that's why i'm asking :D) when reporting an error here.

Comment: I noticed that `char arr[5] __attribute__((aligned(16));` gives the proper compiler error on g++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a compiler bug. The compiler sees `__attribute__` followed by two opening parentheses, some other tokens and then two closing parentheses, which is probably the “definition” of what an `__attribute__` should look like, e.g.

> <attribute> ::= `__attribute__` `'(('` something `'))'`

My guess is that the tokens in between are being interpreted as `aligned(16` and by some miracle it still works.

Comment: Perfect. I've just reported this as a bug on gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: Yes, it probably has to do with `aligned()` more than with `__attribute__`, since `__attribute__((packed)` does not compile.

Comment: It may not be a bug, in my eyes it is because unbalanced parentheses are hardly ever what you want, but if GCC allows any sort of tokens to appear within the `((` and `))` then it may not be considered a bug. Try `__attribute__(( ( ( ( ( ( ))` and see whether that complains about an unknown attribute rather than unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Apparently, it was a bug which was reported on 2009, but hasn't been fixed yet.